# Correlation function in NetLogo

Tags: fft, netlogo, correlation

I would like to compute the spatial correlation length of a patch variable. Normally I would do it by taking the integral of the correlation function of that variable, but how to compute such a function with NetLogo? Since I my project deals with  periodic 2d world, I could use FFT transform to compute the correlation, but I do not know if any extension for NetLogo exists that implement Fourier transform.